# onclick event - why Javascript runs it onload

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, dom-events

```
<p id="specialp">some content</p>
<script>
document.getElementById('specialp').onclick=alert('clicked');
</script>
```

I'm just starting out with Javascript, and I don't understand why the alert is executed when page loads, but not when I click that paragraph.

The handler works as I expect when I put it inline, like this:

```
<p id="specialp" onclick="alert('clicked')" >some content</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you didnt wrap the `onclick` assignment as an actual function, so it attempts to assign the result of `alert('clicked')` to the onclick event handler (which means it's probably `undefined` when assigned). What you need to do is assign a function to that handler like so:

```
document.getElementById('specialp').onclick = function()
{
    alert('clicked');
};
```

When you do the same thing in HTML, the DOM automatically wraps that content in a function for you.

Comment: Isn't alert() a function itself? Does that imply that if, somehow, alert() returned true this approach would work?

Plus, why is it executed after the page loads?

Comment: `alert` is a function, but you're not assigning it that function, you're assigning the expression `alert('clicked')` to the onclick object. The expression is evaluated as part of the assignment. What you did is technically no different than `var x = 4 + 2`. The script runs on load, and would assign 6 to `x`, not at some later point when `x` is used.

Comment: If I wanted to use some attribute of the element in the function, how would I pass the object in an argument to that function, and what would it be like? I'm using this for all elements on the page, so I can't use the getElementById() function.

Comment: `this` would be the context of the calling element for the function. IE: `function() { alert(this.id); }`

Comment: var x=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0;x[i]!=null;i++) {x[i].onclick=function() {alert(this.href);this.preventDefault();this.stopPropagation();};}

Could you please tell me the reason for this not to work?

Comment: Define 'not work' - Are you talking about the alert constantly displaying the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the default event prevention.

Comment: You can always just `return false` - it means the same as `preventDefault` + `stopPropagation`.

Comment: Works. Thank you, that's all I needed to know for now.