# Why is the onClick event triggered twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML content:

```html
<span onclick="alert('Boem')">
    <button id="test1">test</button>
</span>
```

When I call the following JavaScript code:

```js
$('#test1').trigger('click');
```

The onclick event is triggered twice, while I expect it to just trigger once. Because jQuery should look up in the DOM tree and find only one onclick.

I do not have control of the span, it is generated in a third party tool. I do have control over the button and his parameters.

You can find a JSFiddle example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Voga/v4100zke/

I do not know the contents of the onclick listener of the span. This is also generated by the third-party tool. I want the click trigger to execute this onclick like it does now, but only once.

Comment: <span>
    <button id="test1" onclick="alert('Boem')">test</button>
</span>, use this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: At least if you don't have control to the span, you could do `$('#test1).parent().trigger('click')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the onclick element will trigger twice for label element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is calling twice because the button is inside a span and span has `onclick="alert('Boem')"`, hence when you trigger click on the button then it shows an alert and the same click event propagates to span and shows the alert once again.

You need to stop default behaviour of button using below code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test1').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();}).click();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/v4100zke/10/)**

Comment: But I do want to propagate to the parent span because that is where the click event is (And I cannot control it). I just want it to fire the event only once so show 'boem' only once

Comment: Is there any requirement to fire click event on page load?

Comment: Nope this is not a requirement

Comment: If I prevent propagation I would expect that nothing is executed because the button itself does not have a onclick attribute?

Comment: have you checked my updated answer demo link, is this what you are looking for? What is your requirement exactly?

Comment: The behaviour of your code is indeed the behaviour I need. Just seeking the why? So when a fire an onclick event on the button, jquery will find all handlers of this event for that button including the handlers of his parents. Next for every parent the same happens because of the propagation. Is this correct? So by stopping the propagation only all the handlers of the button are executed but this includes the handler of the span?

Comment: Here in your case, we are preventing button's default onclick behaviour and not stopping propagation of click event. And when we click on button its click event propagate to its parent span which triggers its onclick function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59187/discussion-between-vogabe-and-bhushan-kawadkar).

Comment: Oke thanx for the clarification. If I would use the stop propagation instead of the preventDefault, my explaination of the behaviour in my previous comment is correct?

Comment: `e.stoppropagation()` will stop the bubling of event towards parent element in DOM, for more info see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp). And `.click()` will trigger click event on button element but it will not call the bind click function but default click behaviour for first time. hence showing alert in onclick of span. see for [this](http://api.jquery.com/click/)  more information.

Comment: Also to know difference in stoppropagation and prevendefault see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Comment: Also use 

$(function(){
$('#test1').click(function(e){
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
});

Answer (score 36):

I was also getting a similar issue where I had to download a pdf which was downloading twice. I used jQuery's **stopImmediatePropagation** method.

```
$( "#test1" ).on("click", function(e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('#test1').trigger('click');
```

***stopImmediatePropagation*** will prevent any parent handlers and also any other handlers from executing. Refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) for more details.

Comment: In my case this did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: perfect thank you!!

Comment: This answer has all that right to get accepted!

Answer (score 12):

To stop event propagation, use: **stopPropagation**

```
$( "#test1" ).on( "click", function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
});

$('#test1').trigger('click');
```

Please note the order events are assigned in DOM.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4100zke/7/)

Answer (score 5):

Bubbling. The click event on the child also happens on the parent (span).

Comment: But why does it trigger 2 times. I know that the trigger on the button also triggers the parents so in this case the span, but it is the only element with an onclick. So I would expect that this onclick will trigger only once?

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem on Modal

Solved by the following tricks -

```
$('#saveButton').off('click').on('click', { modal: modal }, save)
```

Here `off('click')` prevents the save method fires multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355747/onclick-event-why-javascript-runs-it-onload) will help answer the 'why' of it.

A better way would be to just assign a click handler to the element so as to keep your JavaScript code abstracted out of the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/v4100zke/3/

```
$('#test1').click(function() {
    alert('Boem')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `button click is triggered`. Since the `button` is inside the `span` and `onclick` event is defined for `span` the `two alert` are happened.

```
One is by the button
```

and

`other by its parent`(parent have onclick event and button click is triggered).

To avoid two alert, use this

```
<span>
    <button onclick="alert('Boem')" id="test1">test</button>
</span>
```

Comment: But the button doesn't have an onlclick parameter so it doesn't execute anything.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
$($('#test1').parent()).trigger('click');
```

Comment: That was indeed the solution I used to solve the problem temporary. I asked this question to understand the why of this behaviour ;-). And maybe find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Mine was the fact that I was using `.trigger('.element')` and there were two elements with that `element` class.

So, I got more specific, and used `.trigger('.parent .element')` to ensure only one click event happened on a single element, instead of one click event on two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have used jQuery's click method. It will emit both the [DOM's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) mouse click event and jQuery's click event. Then both jQuery's click event and DOM's mouse click event are propagated to the *span* element and its onclick listener is triggered twice, hence it alerts twice.

Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shawn_peng/on0pay77/1/) to figure it out.

As for how to deal with it, just use **stopPropagation** as in previous answers.

```
$('#test1').click(function() {

  // comment this line and run, 'parent' will be alerted TWICE!!! since both mouseEvent and jQuery.Event trigger the onclick listener
  $('#children').click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation()})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Why is the onClick event triggered twice?

This happens because of bubbling. This is because, as [javascript.info says: "*events “bubble” from the inner element up through parents like a bubble in the water*"](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#:%7E:text=events%20%E2%80%9Cbubble%E2%80%9D%20from%20the%20inner%20element%20up%20through%20parents%20like%20a%20bubble%20in%20the%20water.).

### How do I solve it?

If your third-party tool generates your `<span></span>` element with the `onclick` attribute included, this probably means that your tool wants you to treat your *span* directly as your button, without the necessity of creating an additional one as you're doing with your `<button></button>` element.

Here, to fix this error, the best way is to programmatically click the *same* element that contains the handler to avoid propagation:

```js
$('#test1').trigger('click');
```

```css
/* Now, you can take #test1 and make it look and function as a button */

#test1 {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #0078d7;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#test1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<!-- Script to include jQuery v3.3.1 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="test1" onclick="alert('Boem')">test</span>
```

Comment: (Despite its weird form, this answer was probably ***not*** plagiarised, [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) or otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case don't have a nested button, but I had the same problem. I solved adding 'return false;' at the end of the event.

```
$('#test1').click(function() {
    alert('Boem');
    return false;
});
```