# event.target triggers input and label elements in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a `form` and in that I am using **radio** buttons but because of the styling issues i just **hides** them by `display: none` property. And done all the styling on its corresponding `label` element.

```
<form>
  <div class="radio-input">
    <input type="radio" style="display:none;" name="color" value="green" id="g2" />
    <label class="square-box" for="g2"></label>
    <input type="radio" style="display:none;" name="color" value="blue" id="b2" />
    <label class="square-box not-allowed" for="b2"></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now I have attached and event listener on that parent `div` and waiting for an event to bubble. But when i click `label`, *event.target* returns both **label** and **input** element. So that creates a problem.

```
document
  .querySelector(".radio-input")
  .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("not-allowed")) {
      // do something...
    } else {
      // do something...
    }
  };
```

So in this if `label` has **not-allowed** class i wanna do some operation but because *event.target* returns both the elements, `addeventlistener` runs twice and fails the code(basically `if` condition).

So the two possible solutions might be

1. just ignore `input` elements by adding a condition in the `if`
2. *event.target* somehow don't return the `input` element

whatever the solution be please tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25264804/16319071), you can stop default behaviour of the addEventListener like this:

```
document
    .querySelector(".radio-input")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // adding this to your code
        if (event.target.classList.contains("not-allowed")) {
            console.log("not allowed");
        } else {
            console.log("allowed");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also ignore `input` element:

```
document
  .querySelector(".radio-input")
  .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT')return; // if it's input, just return
    if (event.target.classList.contains("not-allowed")) {
      // do something...
    } else {
      // do something...
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above preventDefault() or possibly stopimmediatepropagation()

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.