# addEventListener uses every click instead of button click

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I wanted to write a code, that stores some information in my local storage when I click on a button. The function for the local storage is working fine but the event listener doesn't. The click event is not referring to the button. It refers on every click.

```
        <td>
        <input type="button" value="In den Warenkorb"id="Knopfwarenkorb1">
       <script>
        const el = document.getElementById('Knopfwarenkorb1');
        el.addEventListener('click', zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt1));
       </script>
       </td>
```

Comment: because you are calling the function and returning what it returns to the click event listener.

Comment: Okay and how can I fix it ?

Comment: What's `produkt1`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355747/onclick-event-why-javascript-runs-it-onload

Comment: produkt1 is a JSON of my product that belongs to the local storage when I click the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function instead of call event on load like:

```js
let produkt1 = 'hello';
const el = document.getElementById('Knopfwarenkorb1');
el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt1)
});

function zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(pro){
  console.log(pro);
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input type="button" value="In den Warenkorb" id="Knopfwarenkorb1">
</td>
```

As you can see in the example below the function will call without click

```js
let produkt1 = 'hello';
const el = document.getElementById('Knopfwarenkorb1');
el.addEventListener('click', zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt1));

function zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(pro){
  console.log(pro);
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input type="button" value="In den Warenkorb" id="Knopfwarenkorb1">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference to the method. Because otherwise the click will only execute what zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen is returning.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('Knopfwarenkorb1');
el.addEventListener('click', knopfwarenkorb1Geclicked);

let produkt1 = {'it': 'worked'};

function knopfwarenkorb1Geclicked(event) {
  zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt1);
}

function zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(prod1) {
  console.log(prod1);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="In den Warenkorb" id="Knopfwarenkorb1">
```